# Connect subclasses and class in java

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I have a piece of code. I try to make chess board.Firstly, I want to write every piece of chess board in arrayList(for every piece i have different subclasses)than concatenate in my main method another ArrayList.What should I do in subclasses to print?

```
public class ChessPiece{
    public static void main(String args[]){

     ArrayList<String> inner = new ArrayList<String>();

    System.out.println(inner);//prints only []
}}
```

---

```
public class King extends ChessPiece{
    {
        inner= new ArrayList<String>();
        inner.add(4,"k");

    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't added anything.

Comment: When i wrote inner.add i suppose add k in chessboard. What should i do? @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ

Comment: Please add the full code. `outer` is not declared - this won't compile. And inner at least prints `[]`- as already noted. It is really not clear, what's the problem.

Comment: I try to add some elements in subclasses such as king, bishop than concatenate on my main method. So I have chess Board but I cannot @burna

Comment: A chess piece *is not* a chess board.  It makes no sense to have your `ChessPiece` class extend `ChessBoard`.

Comment: Yes you're right. I tried smth else and I forgot delete. @scottb

Answer (score 1):

> System.out.println(inner);//does not print anything.

I doubt.Even if you don't add anything,it should print

```
[]
```

And in your case,you can add any String to it using [add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)) method.

**UPDATE**

Put all the code of populating arraylist in subclasses as per your need.Create an instance which holds arraylist in main and access that arraylist which you can iterate and print.

Comment: I have to add elements in sub classes, in main method I want only print them.

Comment: Can you give an example. I try to somethings but cannot solve. Thank you!

Comment: @PrinceManiGupta The first part of update 2 is wrong. It's not true that you can't do `inner.add(4, "k")`. The two-arguments `add` method exists, and is used to add an element to a specific position. In that case, it means "Add `k` at index `4`. [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#add(int,%20E))

Comment: Yes I try to k in a specific position but I cannot print anyway to write inner.add("k"); or inner.add(4,"k"); . @PrinceManiGupta